# Convert variable

Tags: mysql

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS hello_world;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    declare coba int;
    select ISNULL(MAX(convert(RIGHT(kode_bahan,3),int)),0) from bahan into coba;
    return coba;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'int)),0) from bahan into coba;
>       return coba; END' at line 6 Line 3, column 1

i cannot find the solution.
please help me.
thanks

Comment: I don't know MySQL very well, but try replacing that line with `SELECT coba = ISNULL(MAX(convert(RIGHT(kode_bahan,3),int)),0) from bahan`

Comment: Also, why does your function return TEXT in the top declaration, but then you return an int?

Comment: at first i try to return text variable then i forgot to change it to int. thx for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with regard to the error code 1064, the MySQL manual page for [CONVERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) does not list `int` as one of the recognized types. Try `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` (followed by the optional keyword `INTEGER` if you prefer).